# Make type deeply writable

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to transform a typescript object type deeply writable, but also remove `readonly` type operator from array types?

Similar to [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/writable.d.ts), but - as I mentioned - also remove `readonly` from array types.

```
// if initial type is:
interface InitialType {
  readonly field: string;
  readonly array: readonly { readonly arraySubfield: string; }[];
  readonly obj: {
    readonly objSubfield1: string;
    readonly objSubfield2: readonly string[];
  };
}

// then the result type would be:
interface ResultType {
  field: string;
  array: { arraySubfield: string }[];
  obj: {
    objSubfield1: string;
    objSubfield2: string[];
  };
}

// achieved by doing this:
type ResultType = Writable<InitialType>;
```

Comment: Doesn't `DeepWritable` from [`ts-essentials`](https://github.com/ts-essentials/ts-essentials) do the trick?

Comment: @Blackhole Don't know. I did not even know this library existed. I will check it out. In the meanwhile, I see it has a lot of useful tools I found myself needing in the past. Thanks for letting me know it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go, a deep writable type that handles way too many things:

```
type Writable<T> =
    // check for things that are objects but don't need changing
    T extends ((...args: any[]) => any) | Date | RegExp
        ? T
        : T extends ReadonlyMap<infer K, infer V> // maps
            ? Map<Writable<K>, Writable<V>> // make key and values writable
            : T extends ReadonlySet<infer U> // sets
                ? Set<Writable<U>> // make elements writable
                : T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> // is an array or tuple?
                    ? `${bigint}` extends `${keyof T & any}` // is tuple
                        ? { -readonly [K in keyof T]: Writable<T[K]> }
                        : Writable<T[number]>[] // is regular array
                    : T extends object // is regular object
                        ? { -readonly [K in keyof T]: Writable<T[K]> }
                        : T; // is primitive or literal value
```

Essentially it's this:

```
type Writable<T> = T extends object ? { -readonly [K in keyof T]: Writable<T[K]> } : T;
```

but it handles a lot more things correctly. Things like (and only) arrays dates, functions, regex, maps, sets, tuples, readonly maps, and readonly sets.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wo5eLN)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `readonly` modifier from nested objects and arrays of `T`, I recommend using the [`DeepWritable<T>`](https://github.com/ts-essentials/ts-essentials/tree/master/lib/deep-writable) utility type from the [ts-essentials](https://github.com/ts-essentials/ts-essentials) package:

```js
import type { DeepWritable } from "ts-essentials";

type ResultType = DeepWritable<InitialType>;
```

As you can see from its [source](https://github.com/ts-essentials/ts-essentials/blob/master/lib/deep-writable/index.ts), the `DeepWritable` utility provides various special cases for types like `Map` and `Set`, so it's probably better to rely on a maintained library than rolling your own.

(Thanks to [@Blackhole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057033/blackhole) for the pointer.)